# Command Not Found while trying to run delayed_job

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

After installing delayed_job gem and run it succesfully on my local machine I cant get it to run on my dedicated server.

I included the gem "daemons" in the Gemfile, generated the active record tables, and bundle installed / migrated successfully. The file delayed_job is sitting in my bin folder.

Yet when I try to execute

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start
```

Im getting

```
exec: command not found
```

Any ideas why im getting this error? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You are getting this error because the `bin/delayed_job` script are missing. This can be caused by Capistrano "symlinking" the `bin` directory to share it between deploys. To fix this, edit your `config/deploy.rb` file and change the line:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

To

```
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}
```

Then try to deploy again :)